# Google Indexing URL that is a 301 redirect

Tags: seo, google, redirects, 301-redirect, google-index

My website URL structure is:

```
http://www.example.com/{record-type}/{record-id}/{human-readable-name}
```

If an invalid human readable name is provided, the page 301 redirects to the correct URL.

I've noticed recently that Google has started indexing partial URLs, i.e:

```
http://www.example.com/{record-type}/{record-id}/
```

If I make requests to those indexed URLs, I am 301 redirected to the correct page.

Is there a way to force Google to use the 301 redirected URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 301 redirect *should* be doing this already. You should verify that the 301 redirect is being sent out especially to googlebot.

Another way to do this is to use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to tell Google which URL they should display in their search results.

Comment: I have verified the 301s work via Curl (including with using a gbot useragent). Also, If one of partial links are clicked from the SERPs the page is 301 redirected to the correct URL. I'll take a look at canonical URLs.

Comment: @drtldr - Did you ever work this out? Same is happening to my site(s), Google is indexing the 301's. In Webmaster Tools, if I fetch the 301 page, it actually fetches the content, doesn't indicate there's a 301. But Fiddler/Chrome Developer Tools all tell me (correctly) there's a 301 redirect. Any update?

Comment: I just checked Bing and it has the same problem.

Comment: I haven't seen any negative SEO indicators from this (with close to 17 million pages indexed), so I stopped actively investigating. However, As this answer suggests, I suspect providing a rel=canonical HTTP header (not html tag!) along with the 301 response should sort it for you.

Comment: drtldr: You can't send that in an HTTP header. Only headers that are written as `http-equiv` can be sent like that. Canonical is `rel`.